# Why doesn't this simple SQL query work?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I'm working on SQL Server 2008 and I have this query which should be quite simple, but for some reason doesn't work. It basically looks like that:

```
SELECT TOP 10
    u.Id                AS "UserId",
    u.CreationDate      AS "Member since",
    AVG(q.Score)        AS "Average Question Rating",  
    COUNT(q.Id)         AS "N. of Questions posted by the agent",
    AVG(a.Score)        AS "Average Answer Rating",  
    COUNT(a.Id)         AS "N. of Answers posted by the agent"
FROM    
        Users u, 
        Answers a, 
        Questions q
WHERE q.OwnerUserId = u.Id
AND a.OwnerUserId = u.Id
GROUP BY u.Id, u.CreationDate
```

When I only work on either the Answers table or the Questions table, everything is ok. But as soon as I try to do both at once (like in the query above), the COUNTs don't work at all. What I get is that the COUNT(a.Id) is identical to the COUNT(q.Id). So I tried reducing my query to see what was wrong, and I realized that I just had to add the Questions or the Answers table (even without using them anywhere) to the FROM clause when working with the other table and everything was ruined.

I'm sure it's something ridiculously trivial that I have overlooked but it's driving me crazy, I'd be thankful if anybody could point me what went wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: first thing, you should just proper JOIN syntax on your joins instead of the commas between the table names

Comment: You've joined on `q.OwnerUserId` into both tables.  But I'm guessing that each owner has more than one question and/or more than one answer.  And if that's true, then you're going to get a cartesian product of all the persons's questions & answers, rather than only a list of each of them individually.

Comment: SQL doesn't work this way. When including both Answers and Questions you will get the cross product grouped by userid. That means you get Answers of a user * Questions of a user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not joining `Answers` and `Questions` correctly for the aggregation. Between `Answers` and `Questions`, the result is a cartesian product (for every user, every answer is coupled with every question)

The simplest way to correct this is to perform aggregation in subqueries:

```
SELECT TOP 10
    u.Id                AS "UserId",
    u.CreationDate      AS "Member since",
    ISNULL((SELECT AVG(Score) FROM Answers   WHERE OwnerUserId = u.Id), 0)
                        AS "Average Question Rating",  
           (SELECT COUNT(*)   FROM Answers   WHERE OwnerUserId = u.Id)        
                        AS "N. of Questions posted by the agent",
    ISNULL((SELECT AVG(Score) FROM Questions WHERE OwnerUserId = u.Id), 0)
                        AS "Average Answer Rating",  
           (SELECT COUNT(*)   FROM Questions WHERE OwnerUserId = u.Id)
                        AS "N. of Answers posted by the agent"
FROM  Users u
```

Alternatively using joins:

```
SELECT TOP 10
     u.Id                AS "UserId",
     u.CreationDate      AS "Member since",
     ISNULL(q.a, 0)      AS "Average Question Rating",  
     ISNULL(q.c, 0)      AS "N. of Questions posted by the agent",
     ISNULL(a.a, 0)      AS "Average Answer Rating",  
     ISNULL(a.c, 0)      AS "N. of Answers posted by the agent"
FROM Users u
-- If you LEFT JOIN these tables, you'll get also results for users without
-- questions or answers
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT OwnerUserId, AVG(Score) a, COUNT(*) c 
     FROM Questions GROUP BY OwnerUserId) q
     ON  q.OwnerUserId = u.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT OwnerUserId, AVG(Score) a, COUNT(*) c 
     FROM Answers GROUP BY OwnerUserId) a
     ON  a.OwnerUserId = u.Id
```

I don't know SQL Server's query optimiser well enough, so I can't say which one is going to be faster. The first solution *could* take advantage of scalar subquery caching, if that is available in SQL Server. Otherwise, the second query *maybe* performs less nested loops.

Comment: @JérémieClos: It happens to the best :)

Answer (score 3):

As noted elsewhere, your join on user ID on both questions and answers essentially produces a cartesian join at the user level between the two tables. A better approach would be to use a union:

```
SELECT TOP 10
    u.Id                AS "UserId",
    u.CreationDate      AS "Member since",
    AVG(q_score)        AS "Average Question Rating",  
    COUNT(q_id)         AS "N. of Questions posted by the agent",
    AVG(a_score)        AS "Average Answer Rating",  
    COUNT(a_id)         AS "N. of Answers posted by the agent"
FROM Users u
JOIN (select OwnerUserId,
             Score        q_score,
             Id           q_id,
             NULL         a_score,
             NULL         a_id
      from Answers
      union all
      select OwnerUserId,
             NULL         q_score,
             NULL         q_id,
             Score        a_score,
             Id           a_id
      from Questions) qa
  ON qa.OwnerUserId = u.Id
GROUP BY u.Id, u.CreationDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't just counting the DISTINCT Ids work?

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    u.Id                         AS "UserId", 
    u.CreationDate               AS "Member since", 
    AVG(q.Score)                 AS "Average Question Rating",   
    COUNT(DISTINCT q.Id)         AS "N. of Questions posted by the agent", 
    AVG(a.Score)                 AS "Average Answer Rating",   
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.Id)          AS "N. of Answers posted by the agent" 
FROM     
        Users u,  
        Answers a,  
        Questions q 
WHERE q.OwnerUserId = u.Id 
AND a.OwnerUserId = u.Id 
GROUP BY u.Id, u.CreationDate
```

Comment: Agree, `COUNT(DISTINCT)` would help in fixing the counts, but not the averages.

Comment: @AndriyM: As a matter of fact, it *might* just work, as every question is equally duplicated by the number of answers. While this would be wrong for `SUM()`, it *might* be curiously correct for `AVG()`. Of course, that's not the right way to go...

Comment: @LukasEder: *Mais oui*! Neatly spotted.

Comment: I was only looking at the COUNTs as that is what was being asked in the question, yeah you're right its not going to work for the `AVG()`

Comment: @domager: Actually, as Lukas pointed out, I'm (most probably) wrong, and the `AVG()` results *will* be correct in this case, but only because it's `AVG`. The average is the sum divided by the count, and if there are duplicates, then both the sum and the count will increase proportionally, thus *not* affecting the resulting average values. If it was `SUM()` instead of `AVG()`, the results would clearly be incorrect, but as it is, the only issue is likely going to be efficiency.

Answer (score -1):

If it were me I would do explicit joins on those other tables (answers and questions). how is it linking the other tables if you don't do a join?

```
SELECT TOP 10
    u.Id                AS "UserId",
    u.CreationDate      AS "Member since",
    AVG(q.Score)        AS "Average Question Rating",  
    COUNT(q.Id)         AS "N. of Questions posted by the agent",
    AVG(a.Score)        AS "Average Answer Rating",  
    COUNT(a.Id)         AS "N. of Answers posted by the agent"
FROM    
        Users u, 
        Answers a, 
        Questions q
WHERE q.OwnerUserId = u.Id
AND a.OwnerUserId = u.Id
GROUP BY u.Id, u.CreationDate

would be

SELECT TOP 10
    u.Id                AS "UserId",
    u.CreationDate      AS "Member since",
    AVG(q.Score)        AS "Average Question Rating",  
    COUNT(q.Id)         AS "N. of Questions posted by the agent",
    AVG(a.Score)        AS "Average Answer Rating",  
    COUNT(a.Id)         AS "N. of Answers posted by the agent"
FROM    
        Users u
JOIN Answers a on u.ID = a.ID (assuming thats how answers and users are linked).
JOIN Questions q on a.ID = q.ID (assuming thats how questions and answers are linked)
WHERE q.OwnerUserId = u.Id
AND a.OwnerUserId = u.Id
GROUP BY u.Id, u.CreationDate
```

Comment: The OP did join the table using `q.OwnerUserId = u.Id AND a.OwnerUserId = u.Id`...

Comment: -1 - While this syntax is often accepted as 'better' (And I much prefer it myself), you need to realize that a comma-seperated `FROM` clause uses 'implicit' joins (And he has the join criteria listed rather nicely).  Furthermore, this will _not_ solve the OP's actual problem, as it's the very fact that he's _performing_ the join with **both** `Answers` and `Questions` that is resulting in 'wrong' results.